# Change IIS Bindings HostName to use other than localhost/server name

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I've made an ASP NET page, and put it on a Windows 2008R2 server running IIS and DNS. (Those are the only 2 roles in server manager.)

Without me touching anything the following urls work to get to my site:

ServerName = REALLYCOOLSERVER, IPAddress: 123.123.123.123

```
http://REALLYCOOLSERVER/App/Login.aspx 
http://123.123.123.123/App/Login.aspx
http://localhost/App/Login.aspx
```

I am on a domain.

I would like to be able to have users of the site navigate to something like:

```
http://foo/App/Login.aspx
```

Here's what I've been trying:

Opened IIS Manager, Sites > Edit bindings

There is one row here with Type: http, Host Name: blank, Port: 80, IP Address: *

From what I've read, I simply needed to edit this row, and set a Host name: *foo*

Then in DNS manager, Forward Lookup Zone > New Zone > Primary Zone (company.com) > Create new file with this file name (company.com.dns) > Do not allow dynamic updates > Finish

This produces the 3 types: Start of Authority(SOA), Name Server(NS), and Host(A) rows.

The A row's name is the server name, with Data being IP Address (123.123.123.123)

My research shows me if I create an Alias (CNAME) with:

```
Alias name: foo
Fully qualified domain name (FQDN): foo.company.com
Fully qualified domain name for target host: Browse > to A record..so.. servername.company.com
```

However, when I got to IIS Manager and click on Browse foo on *:80(http), I get a broken link. Also, in my browser when I got to http://foo/App/Login.aspx it's also a broken link.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried first making sure that the site works locally. For example edit the file c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and add a row that has something like "127.0.0.1 foo" (without the quotes). And navigate to http://foo/... and make sure that works. If that works, then the culprits are either DNS or firewall if remotely.

Comment: Yes, I added the name to the hosts file, and it works as expected. However, it does not work remotely on another PC on the same domain. I'm guessing if I edited everyone's host file, that would work, however that seems unfeasible. Any ideas?

Comment: These are pretty much the instructions I've followed: http://www.geekshangout.com/content/multiple-websites-single-iis-server-using-host-header

Comment: Yeah, definitely do not edit user's hosts files, it was just a test to make sure that the IIS setup and the machine was all good. So you can rule that out, at this point it is a DNS configuration issue and that should help you focus on that. (you can just verify to make sure firewall is good by editing the hosts file in another machine, and then you know once your dns configuration is correct everything will work).